# mysql declaring and setting variables. syntax errors

Tags: mysql

I thought this would be a simple task but i cannot figure out why this gives me an error in my syntax.  Any help is appreciated.

```
DECLARE @usernameid VARCHAR(20);
declare @UserIDParam VARCHAR(20);
SET @usernameid = 'myid';
SET @UserIDParam =
   (SELECT userid
      FROM tblusers
     WHERE unid = usernameid);

SELECT *
 FROM tblusers
 WHERE tblusers.userID = @useridparam
```

Comment: how about you show us your error

Comment: As an aside, if that is really your entire code, why don't you just reduce the whole thing to a single `SELECT` query with a [SQL join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One doesn't `DECLARE` user variables: one just uses them.  (You `DECLARE` *local* variables e.g. in a procedure).

Comment: can i get an example how to change this?

Comment: @Mike: Just entirely remove the two `DECLARE` statements.

Comment: @Mike: In your comment to Gratzy's answer, you said the error was on the `DECLARE` statement - how can you obtain the *same* error if the `DECALRE` statements aren't there?

Comment: eggyal oh you mean remove the entire line, okay i got past that not i its at Unknown system variable 'usernameid'

Comment: @Mike: You need to prefix your reference to `usernameid` with `@` in your first `SELECT` statement.

Comment: and i also needed to keep the set instead of select